# Windows 10 tab control

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

How to get 'tab' control which look like this? Should I edit Pivot control or any other, better ideas?

[image]

Comment: Looks like some fancy radio buttons to me... Unfortunately, a full implemenation of that is far too involved for a Stack Overflow question. After you have started working on it, feel free to ask if you run into specific questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Universal Windows Examples collection you have one called Pivot: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot this shows how to Use pivots across devices, with mouse, keyboard touch, Show custom header content, tabs with icons, etc. a great example

Comment: Great but how can we stop looping of pivot control. I tried but unable to do that.

Comment: You mean when you slide horizontally the pivot item?

Comment: Yes, I want to stop swiping the pivot Item (slide horizontally) when the pivot reaches at its last pivot item. Don't want to be swipe to first pivot item.